# Use ActiveStorage to serve videos directly uploaded to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using `ActiveStorage` to allow users to upload videos to Amazon S3 and for them to view them at a later date.  The videos are an attachment in a model Lesson.

```
#app/models/lesson.rb
class Lesson
  has_one_attached :video
end
```

and the html to stream the video is

```
<video controls class='video_size'>
  <source src=<%= rails_blob_path(lesson.video) %> type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

However, I have a number of videos that I have created that I want to allow users to view.  These videos have already be uploaded directly to the same S3 bucket, so I know the amazon url of the videos.

Is there a way of directly creating an ActiveStorage blob using these known urls ie.

@special_blob = create_blob_from_amazon_url(amazon_url)

and then in the view

```
<video controls class='video_size'>
   <source src=<%= rails_blob_path(@special_blob) %> type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

or do I have to upload the videos using ActiveStorage to create a blob?

Comment: Where you able to figure this one out?

Comment: No, I came to suspect that uploading via active storage actually adds some preprocessing so the videos download faster.  So I ended up creating a new model for these videos and then attaching them as active storage attachments. It would be good if someone could confirm it is best to go the active storage upload route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `#build/create_after_upload!` :

https://medium.com/weareevermore/manual-uploads-using-activestorage-47808dab1b65

https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveStorage/Blob/create_after_upload%21/class